# Why does PolynomialQ[x^n, x] return False?

Tags: functions, special-functions, polynomials, expression-test

From what I can see `PolynomialQ` will return `False` whenever some exponent is another variable such as here:

```
    PolynomialQ[x^n, x]
```

Is there an alternative test that will return `True` for such a polynomial?

**Motivation:**

In [another thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38919/no-response-to-%5C%20an-infinite-limit) I need to use

```
Product[x^k (1 - x^k), {k, 1, n}]
```

for which *Mathematica* returns:

```
x^(1/2 n (1 + n)) QPochhammer[x, x, n]
```

However those two forms do not expand in the same way, for instance with $n=3$:

```
With[{n = 3},
  Expand[{x^(1/2 n (1 + n)) QPochhammer[x, x, n], Product[x^k (1 - x^k), {k, 1, n}]}]]
(* {x^6 QPochhammer[x, x, 3], x^6 - x^7 - x^8 + x^10 + x^11 - x^12} *)
```

Indeed, *Mathematica* treats only the second expression as a polynomial:

```
With[{n = 3}, PolynomialQ[#, x] & /@ 
  {x^(1/2 n (1 + n)) QPochhammer[x, x, n], Product[x^k (1 - x^k), {k, 1, n}]}]
(* {False, True} *)
```

even if I specify that n is integer as follows

```
f[x_, n_Integer] := x^(1/2 n (1 + n)) QPochhammer[x, x, n];
PolynomialQ[f[n], x]
(* False *)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Assuming[n ∈ Integers && n > 0, PolynomialQ[x^n, x]]` won't work because `Assuming` only works on functions with `Assumptions` option, such as `Simplify`, `Refine`, etc. Unfortunately `PolynomialQ` doesn't have this option. Still, something like

```
Simplify[PolynomialQ[x^n, x], n ∈ Integers && n > 0]
```

won't work because *Mathematica* will calculate `PolynomialQ[x^n, x]` first.

Currently the only solution in my mind is to define a new function:

```
pQ[poly_, var_, assum_] := PolynomialQ[poly /. Thread[assum -> 1], var]
```

The first argument of `pQ` is the possible polynomial, the second argument is the variables of the possible polynomial, the third argument is the variables which are assumed to be integers and positive. This function is in fact a realization of the method suggested by @Mark Adler. It can be used it like this:

```
pQ[x^n, x, n]
pQ[x^(n + m), x, {n, m}]
pQ[x^(n + 1/m), x, {n, 1/m}]
pQ[x^(n + 1/m), x, n + 1/m]
```

> ```
> True 
> True 
> True 
> True
> ```

---

Well, I admit this solution isn't robust enough. Changing the definition of the function into something like

```
pQ[poly_, var_, assum_] := PolynomialQ[poly /. Thread[assum ->RandomInteger[{1, 100}]], var]
```

can somewhat help, but it still has a certain probability to fail…

However, for your added **Motivation** part, `FunctionExpand` will give the desired result:

```
With[{n = 3}, 
 FunctionExpand[{x^(1/2 n (1 + n)) QPochhammer[x, x, n], 
   Product[x^k (1 - x^k), {k, 1, n}]}]]
```

> ```
> {(1 - x) x^6 (1 - x^2) (1 - x^3), (1 - x) x^6 (1 - x^2) (1 - x^3)}
> ```

Comment: From what I understand of your code, it tests `poly` after replacing integer variables by 1. I would like to avoid being tricked if I test `pQ[x^(1/n), x, n]` (returns `True`).

Comment: @A.G. I'm sorry that I can't find a robust enough way to solve this, but for your **Motivation** part, you can use `FunctionExpand` to expand the two expressions in the same way.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently *you* know somehow that `n` is a non-negative integer, but Mathematica has no idea.  `n` could be anything.  You need to let Mathematica know.

Since `PolynomialQ` doesn't honor `Assuming`, you would need to make your own that does.  Using `Simplify` could incorporate the assumptions.

Here is my attempt at it (though my pattern-fu is not very strong -- e.g. I couldn't get `Repeated` to work right, so I just used `Map`):

```
pq[p_, x_] := 
 And @@ (MatchQ[#, (c_ /; FreeQ[c, x]) | ( 
        c_. x^n_. /; 
         FreeQ[c, x] && FreeQ[n, x] && 
          Simplify[n ∈ Integers && n >= 0])] & /@ 
    If[Head[p] === Plus, List @@ p, {p}])
```

Then:

```
pq[x^n, x]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

```
Assuming[{n ∈ Integers, n >= 0}, pq[x^n, x]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
Assuming[{n ∈ Integers, n >= 0}, pq[x^(n - 2), x]]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

```
Assuming[{n ∈ Integers, n >= 2}, pq[x^(n - 2), x]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

This could probably be extended to take a list of variables, as `PolynomialQ` permits, instead of just one but I will leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Of course I would like to get the correct answer without replacing $n$. I tried to tell Mathematica about $n$ like this: `Assuming[n \[Element] Integers && n > 0, PolynomialQ[x^n, x]]` but I still get `False`.